# Элементы списка разными цветами с помощью :nth-child()

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ребята, я новичок и пытаюсь изучать css. Сейчас изучаю селектор nth-child. У меня есть список, где первым идет красный цвет, вторым - желтый, а третьим зеленый.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новых элементов они также становились цветными в заданной последовательности.

```css
li:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Красный</li>
  <li>Желтый</li>
  <li>Зеленый</li>
  <li>Новый цвет</li>
</ul>
```

Но когда я к этим трем добавляю четвертую лишку, то она становится не красной, а
желтой. И в инспекторе браузера почему то красный цвет зачеркнут. Почему так?

Comment: если зачеркнут, значит какой то другой стиль его переписывает. посмотрите в инспекторе ниже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На сколько я смог понять вопрос  - Вы не верно трактуете указание внутри скобок у `nth-child`.

`:nth-child(`**`3n+1`**`)` итд это то что Вы ищите

В этой директиве написано что надо красить каждый **третий + 1** элемент.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

div:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: teal;
}

div:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```